# R: counting rows by matching against a variable column name

Tags: r

I'm trying to use a variable as the column name when counting rows that matches a certain value in a certain column of a data.frame, for example;

```
matches <- 0
cols <- c("B1","B2","B3","S1")
for (i in length(cols)) {
    matches <- matches + nrow(dt[cols[i]=="some value"]) 
}
```

I have tries subset too with no success:

```
nrow(subset(dt, cols[i]=="some value"))
```

Any suggestion on how I can do this?

Comment: If you could you show a short version of `dt`, that would help us understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Try `sum(dt[cols] == "some value")`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to use `get` to convert the string to a variable name

```
nrow(subset(dt, get(cols[i])=="some value"))
```

Comment: I didn't down vote, tried to up vote but I can't vote yet: 
"Vote Up requires 15 reputation"

Comment: @Johan Sorry that was just a general comment

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what the class of the `dt`. From what you present above, I guess it would be `data.frame`.

The most thing makes me feel confused is `subset(dt, cols[i]=="some value")` or `dt[cols[i]=="some value"]` in your code.

I guess the `cols` is the *colnames* of `dt` and you want count the frequency of `"some value"` in the `dt`.

You can try this,

```
length(dt[dt=="some value"])
```

or specific the columns of `dt`,

```
subdt <- dt[,cols]
length(subdt[subdt == "some value"])
```

Wish it will helps.